# Problems with hyperref package

Tags: beamer, pdftex, hyperref

I want to put a video on my `beamer` presentation using `\href`. 
When I use `\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}` don't compiles, and if I use just `\usepackage{hyperref}` compiles, but when I open on Okular or Adobe says that "the movie can not be found".
I don't understand, I put the video in the same folder than the .tex
Why is this happening?
Can somebody help me?

That's the error when I use `\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}`

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can help us to help you by providing the code for a small document that shows your problem. Just edit your question and add the code.

Comment: You should not need to use `\usepackage{hyperref}` altogether, as beamer already loads it for you.

Answer (score 2):

Class `beamer` already loads package `hyperref`. Additional options can be specified by class option `hyperref`:

```
\documentclass[hyperref={...}]{beamer}
```

Driver option `pdftex` does not need to be specified, because `hyperref` automatically detects pdfTeX in PDF mode.